# Jasmine specs fail with Velocity.js animations an $.Velocity.mock = true

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine, sinon, velocity.js

I'm attempting to run some Jasmine specs on some functions that contain animations built with Velocity.js

The method looks like this:

```
@changeTitle = (e, data) ->
  newTitle = data.title
  $pageTitle = @select("pageTitleSelector")

  $pageTitle.velocity
    opacity: 0
  ,
    duration: 750
    complete: -> $pageTitle.text(newTitle)
  .velocity
    opacity: 1
    duration: 800
```

I'm trying to tests that the page's title changes to the new title. Here is my Jasmine spec:

```
describe 'submit uiTitleChange', ->
it 'changes the title', ->
  @clock = sinon.useFakeTimers()
  @component.trigger "uiTitleChange", {title: "New Title"}
  @clock.tick(16)
  expect(@component.select("pageTitleSelector")).toContainHtml "New Title"
  @clock.restore()
```

Now, I use requirejs, and have a shim that adds `$.Velocity.mock = true` before any test so that animation duration goes to zero (though actually it's more like 16ms to get the next animation frame).

I've verified that `$.Velocity.mock` is indeed true before the animation runs, and when running the spec file alone, this works just fine, but when running my entire suite, which tests a few different animations, several of them always fail.

I've tried using `setTimeout` instead of sinon's fake timers, I've tried setting the clock tick to a very large number (e.g. 100000), and I've also added `$.Velocity.mock` right before the animations in question, and none of these fix the problem.

The failure looks like this:

```
Failure/Error: Expected '<div class="page-title velocity-animating">Old Title</div>' to contain html 'New Title'.
```

The velocity-animating class is there, and the animation's `complete` callback was never called.

Answer (score 1):

mock must be `true` not only before an animation runs, but also before any animation calls are made to begin with.

also, just for doubly good measure -- although you prob already know: the velocity calls are still async with mock (since it's on the next rAF tick)

beyond that, i'm not sure. if you showed me a stripped down codepen.io pen, i could be of more use :)

p.s. i don't use jasmine, but rather qunit

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't seem to help. I put `console.log($.Velocity.mock)` in front of every velocity call in my codebase, and it returns true every time (I'm using a requirejs shim to set `$.Velocity.mock` to true). Also, my test runner uses PhantomJS, which doesn't support rAF natively, so as far as I know it's just using a plain old setTimeout

Comment: If it's using setTimeout it's still async.